# Posting on facebook wall is failed using hello.js

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-graph-api, hello.js

I am using Hello.js to do user interaction with facebook.

I am trying to post some form content . But I am always getting following error

'`#200 user hasn't authorised the application to perform this action` '

Okay I know we have to pass a param in the end of the URL that is

'publish_stream' .

And this scope we should pass to hello.js something like this

```
hello.init({
    facebook: '26fffffffffffffff064',
    google: '438fffffffffffffffffffffffffffgleusercontent.com',
    twitter: 'YHs0fffffffffffffffffffffffffffff0Pgw'
}, {
    redirect_uri: 'http://ffffffffffo.com/',
    scope: 'publish'
});
```

But even after doing this My app still wont let me post on any wall. I tried changing other app number but all gives the same result.

Please help me out

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the correct scope is publish_actions

Comment: yes for facebook javascript API . But in hello . js inorder to pass 'publish_action' in the url you need to call the plugin with scope:publish. Please see line number 3476. of hello.js

Comment: publish_stream is wrong. publish_actions is correct